# Resetting running count to zero at the end/start of every month in Python

Tags: python, pandas, cumulative-sum

I am creating a running count of claims and would like to reset the count to 0 at the start of every month.

I currently have these data frames:

DF1:

| Date | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-25 | 4 | 4 |
| 2021-04-26 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-04-27 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-04-28 | 56 | 53 |
| 2021-04-29 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-04-30 | 1 | 0 |
| 2021-05-01 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-05-02 | 5 | 0 |
| 2021-05-03 | 5 | 5 |
| 2021-05-04 | 0 | 0 |

Df2:

| Date | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-25 | 4 | 4 |
| 2021-04-26 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-04-27 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-04-28 | 56 | 53 |
| 2021-04-29 | 3 | 0 |
| 2021-04-30 | 4 | 0 |
| 2021-05-01 | 4 | 0 |
| 2021-05-02 | 9 | 0 |
| 2021-05-03 | 14 | 5 |
| 2021-05-04 | 9 | 0 |

In order to get to the df2 data frame the following code was used:

```
df2 = df1

df2['X'] = df1['X'] + (df1['X'] - df1['Y']).cumsum().shift(1).fillna(0)
```

I am unsure how or where in this equation I should add the condition to reset count to 0 at the start of every month such that I have the below dataset.

df_final:

| Date | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-25 | 4 | 4 |
| 2021-04-26 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-04-27 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-04-28 | 56 | 53 |
| 2021-04-29 | 3 | 0 |
| 2021-04-30 | 4 | 0 |
| 2021-05-01 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-05-02 | 5 | 0 |
| 2021-05-03 | 10 | 5 |
| 2021-05-04 | 5 | 0 |

Comment: Does this answer your question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72998152/how-to-do-a-running-count-based-on-certain-conditions-in-python/72999480#72999480  I did this in two steps by first calculating the cumsum and then subtracting out the surplus for each month.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

Groupby(df[Date].dt.Month).agg(‘cumsum’)

Comment: Would that be a separate line in the code or part of the equation? If part of the equation, how would I write that?

Comment: Sry doing this from my phone.  It would replace the original df2 equation.

Comment: This solution does not  take into account the addition/subtractions occurring during each month between column X and Y

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ('2021-04-25', 4, 4),
    ('2021-04-26', 0, 0),
    ('2021-04-27', 0, 0),
    ('2021-04-28', 56, 53),
    ('2021-04-29', 0, 0),
    ('2021-04-30', 1, 0),
    ('2021-05-01', 0, 0),
    ('2021-05-02', 5, 0),
    ('2021-05-03', 5, 5),
    ('2021-05-04', 0, 0),
], columns=['Date', 'X', 'Y',])
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

# Create Cumulative Sums for X 
df['X'] = (df['X'] - df['Y'].shift(fill_value=0)).cumsum()

result = pd.concat([
    group.assign(X=(
        group['X'] - group.loc[group['Date'].dt.is_month_start, 'X'].values[0]
        if len(group.loc[group['Date'].dt.is_month_start]) > 0
        else group['X']
    ))
    for month, group in df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.month)
])
```

Output:

```
        Date   X   Y
0 2021-04-25   4   4
1 2021-04-26   0   0
2 2021-04-27   0   0
3 2021-04-28  56  53
4 2021-04-29   3   0
5 2021-04-30   4   0
6 2021-05-01   0   0
7 2021-05-02   5   0
8 2021-05-03  10   5
9 2021-05-04   5   0
```

Comment: Hi, it looks like this code is not resetting the value to 0 on the start of the month. It also also not subtracting x from y and placing the remainder in the following row.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.  It is resetting the value to 0 on the start of the month by subtracting the value from the start of the month from all of that month's X values.

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is that when I used your code, it did not work. It is just gathering the cumulative sum of the columns. No subtraction occurs when I run the code.

Comment: The code above assigns the resulting dataframe to the variable result instead of mutating the df.  Perhaps that's what's going on?  If you run the above code and then print `result` I think you'll find it is meeting your code requirements.

Comment: I appreciate all of your help. I think the issue is arising because I only showed a minimally reproducible example and when I try to apply it to my main dataset it is not working.